# Response code 401 while sending notification to Edge

Tags: .net, nuget, microsoft-edge, html5-notifications

I am creating a web app that sends notifications to my subscribers. While testing with different browsers,  I noticed only the Edge browser got an authorized error and has a different endpoint than the rest of the browsers (Chrome, Opera) `sg2p.notify.windows.com`

I am using Nuget WebPush for send notifications and Conveyor by Keyoti for testing on LAN

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic but I would recommend you edit your question and provide more details. Especially the network traffic from the browser that works and from the browser that does not work. Use developer tools (usually F11 will bring this up) and check the network traffic when you are trying to make a push.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? Can Edge subscribe the notifications? Have you tried to clear cache and cookies in Edge and test again? It the issue still exists, please provide [a minimal, complete, reproducible code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can run and test. It's hard to locate the issue with only the above description.